# d3.js - Issue appending rect to existing rect

Tags: d3.js

I'm building a schedule in d3.js. I've managed to create  bars to represent the timeline,
but now I want to append additional rects to the existing rect to highlight events that happen within that time. The data is attached to the the bar data, so I thought it would be as simple as creating an each function and appending another rect using that data, however I cannot get the additional rects to show. They show in the html when I inspect it, but not visible in the browser. Here is the code i am using, can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
var innerRects = this.graph.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "innerRects")
    .attr("rx", 3)
    .attr("ry", 3)
    .attr("x", (d: any) => this.timeScale(dateFormat(d.startTime)) + this.sidePadding)
    .attr("y",(d, i) =>  i * this.gap + this.topPadding )
    .attr("width", (d: any) => (this.timeScale(dateFormat(d.endTime))-this.timeScale(dateFormat(d.startTime))))
    .attr("height", this.barHeight)
    .attr("stroke", "none")
    .style("cursor", "pointer")
    .style("fill",(d: any) => d.color)
    .each(function(d) {
        const parent = d3.select(this)
        parent.append("rect")
          .data(d)
          .attr("class", "innerRects2")
          .attr("width", (d: any) => (this.timeScale(dateFormat(d.endTime))-this.timeScale(dateFormat(d.startTime))))
          .attr("height", 20)
          .attr("x", (d: any) => this.timeScale(dateFormat(d.startTime)) + this.sidePadding)
          .attr("y", (d, i) =>  i * this.gap + this.topPadding)
          .style("fill",  "red")
    })
```

Comment: You can't append rects to rects, that's not possible with SVG. A common g parent might be easier - also if appending one element at a time to each parent you don't need to use `.data(d)` as the parent datum will be passed to the child.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. So you suggest that I append a g the svg (I.e. this.graph in my code above), the append two separate reacts.  Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Yes, I think that's a good explanation. I can expand in an answer if you want.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, that would be really helpful. I'm new to d3.js and trying to use if for a work project and struggling a little. I really appreciate your help!